# Updating root scope variable with resource value

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

In my main layout I have a heading, like:

```
<h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
```

I can set that to various static values from my controllers using:

```
$rootScope.heading = 'My Heading';
```

But if I try to create a dynamic heading from a resource, its blank:

```
app.controller('ShowAccountController', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, Account) {
  $scope.account = Account.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
  $rootScope.heading = $scope.account.name;
});
```

The account variable is definitely set there (checked via console) so I'm a bit stumped as to why the heading doesn't have a value?

Comment: Chrome's console intelligently updates the logged display value after the async call completes (apparently it passes a reference to the console) even though at the time of the log it is actually undefined because the async call hasn't completed yet.

Comment: @sh0ber How confusing! I'm sure that'll save me (and anyone reading this) some headache in the future. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sh0ber pointed out you are being confused be the way Chrome console works. Anyway, to set the `heading` variable you should use callback:

```
app.controller('ShowAccountController', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, Account) {
  $scope.account = Account.get({ id: $stateParams.id }, function(account){
    $rootScope.heading = account.name;
  });
});
```